# chromium: change scrollbar color using css

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Is it possible to change color of the scrollbar in chromium, without installing an addon?

Perhaps by modifying some css file somewhere?

I am using chromium 83 on Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

You may use
[Rescroller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rescroller/ddehdnnhjimbggeeenghijehnpakijod):

> Rescroller allows you to customize the look and feel of the scrollbars
> on webpages within Google Chrome. Using the included settings, set the
> color, shadows, borders, etc. of each scrollbar element, or write
> custom CSS to style the scrollbars manually.
>
> Find Rescroller on GitHub:
> https://github.com/davidofwatkins/rescroller

Comment: thank you, but I am asking specifically if I can achieve this without having to install yet another addon.